# Drupal 7 views grid format slideshow

Tags: javascript

I am using drupal 7, I want to show the two columns of image with previous and next button on the top. The previous and next button will be used to show the grid format images. I can tried with views grid format, but how can i show the previous and next link of the view? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 1):

You can create slideshows using [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module. You can add thumbnail images below the main slide image. There is a setting already there in views slide show settings.

See this : [Create an Image Slideshow with Drupal using Views](http://www.developersdoc.com/blog/create-image-slideshow-drupal-using-views)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only work with the slideshow format, not grid format. You can have a pager at the bottom when you hit more than a specified number of grid images.